# React navigation weird back button and pop behavior

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-navigation

I have a nested navigator in my react native App

```
cost Main = createTabNavigator({
  Home:Home,
  Challenge:Challenge,
  Products:Products,
  Options:Options
})
const Options = createStackNavigator({
  OptionsScree:OptionsScreen,
  Details:Details,
  Profile:Profile
})
```

I can navigate from Home screen to Details by simply doing `this.props.navigationnavigate('Details')`

but when I'm doing `this.props.navigation.pop()`
it is supposed to take me to last focused screen which was Home screen but it takes me to OptionsScreen
is there a way to go back to Home ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving Main tab navigator component into stack navigator as below.

```
const Options = createStackNavigator({
  Main:Main,
  OptionsScree:OptionsScreen,
  Details:Details,
  Profile:Profile
})
```

As Home screen is not present in stack, `this.props.navigation.pop()` can not pop that screen for you. It pops previous screen in the stack, if none pops the first screen which is in your case is OptionsScreen.